# Grant \system\etc write access from a priviligied app [open failed: EROFS]

Tags: android, android-source

I have an issue to edit `libnfc-nxp.conf` file which is under `\system\etc\`, I get the following error.

> /system/etc/libnfc-nxp.conf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Context: I have access to AOSP and can modify everything on OS.
I want to develop an Android application which can modify this file. This app will be use internally with specific ENG OS build.

So, I know that an application cannot have access to /system/etc/.
To grant this access, I use a system sharedUserID and signed the app to be a system_app. now, I have a priviligied application

> u:r:system_app:s0 system

By default the /system/etc/libnfc-nxp.conf permissions are

> -rw-r--r-- root root libnfc-nxp.conf

So, I tested via adb to remount /system partition with rw, to chown and chmod the file

> chown system:system libnfc-nxp.conf
>
> chmod 666 libnfc-nxp.conf

I still have the same issue..
So, I am looking to update the SElinux to grant {open write} access for system_app to all files under \system\etc.

I modified `system_app.te` under `device/xxx/sepolicy`

> userdebug_or_eng(`
>
> allow system_app sysfs:file rw_file_perms;
>
> allow system_app system_file:file {create open read write getattr setattr };
>
> ')

I did a test and still have the same issue.
I did the round of possible ideas I have in mind. Do you have any suggestions?
Can it still be a SELinux issue and because something is missing.. I am not familiar with SELinux?

Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: The `/system` mount point is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the access issue.
Finally, I changed the way to proceed and updated the NFC service to look the conf file on /sdcard/ folder (instead of /system/etc/). It avoids permission issues.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

JMC,

First of all, did you really do a remount of /system/? If not, run this command and see if that helps (note: this will reset after reboot):
adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system

This is the key to allowing access to r/w to the system partition.

If you are still having problems, disable the enforced mode of SE Linux with this command:
adb shell setenforce 0

That should give you a pass for a bit. You should monitor your app's debug in Android Studio to see if it does need other permissions.